# Illegal instruction (core dumped) while running Dlib Face detection

Tags: python, face-detection, coredump, dlib

I am trying to run face_landmark_detection.py example sample which was provided by the `Dlib` library.

But when i am trying to run the command via ubuntu terminal I am getting error:

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I debug it so i get to know it is because of this line :

```
win=dlib.image_window()
```

I guess something is wrong with this line

I am running code via this command:

./face_landmark_detection.py /home/abhishek/openCV/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat ../examples/faces

As done in the sample code.
my code

```
        import sys
        import os
        import dlib
        import glob
        from skimage import io

        if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print(
    "Give the path to the trained shape predictor model as the first "
    "argument and then the directory containing the facial images.\n"
    "For example, if you are in the python_examples folder then "
    "execute this program by running:\n"
    "    ./face_landmark_detection.py shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat ../examples/faces\n"
    "You can download a trained facial shape predictor from:\n"
    "    http://sourceforge.net/projects/dclib/files/dlib/v18.10/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2")
            exit()

        predictor_path = sys.argv[1]
        faces_folder_path = sys.argv[2]

        print predictor_path
        print faces_folder_path

        detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
        predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_path)
        win = dlib.image_window()


        for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(faces_folder_path, "*.jpg")):

             print("Processing file: {}".format(f))
             img = io.imread(f)

             print "img",img
             win.clear_overlay()
             win.set_image(img)

# Ask the detector to find the bounding boxes of each face. The 1 in the
# second argument indicates that we should upsample the image 1 time. This
# will make everything bigger and allow us to detect more faces.
        dets = detector(img, 1)
        print("Number of faces detected: {}".format(len(dets)))
        for k, d in enumerate(dets):
               print("Detection {}: Left: {} Top: {} Right: {} Bottom:             {}".format(
        k, d.left(), d.top(), d.right(), d.bottom()))
    # Get the landmarks/parts for the face in box d.
            shape = predictor(img, d)
            print("Part 0: {}, Part 1: {} ...".format(shape.part(0),
                                              shape.part(1)))
    # Draw the face landmarks on the screen.
           win.add_overlay(shape)

    win.add_overlay(dets)
    dlib.hit_enter_to_continue()
```

Comment: There are a number of common reasons for Illegal Instruction.  The file could have been downloaded as text rather than binary, or someone has taken a text editor to an executable file and saved it as text.   It could be that you are running with incompatible word lengths, for example a 64-bit python with a 32-bit module (or vice versa).  Or you could be running an executable from a different architecture, for example a Windows binary on a UNIX platform, or Solaris (RISC) on Intel.  Check your installation.

Comment: at least for exectuables, you'd rather get an `exec format error` if you try to run a binary for a different architecture. `illegal instruction` can also come from something more sublte such using a binary compiled compiled to make use instructions of a more recent processor generation (e.g. AVX) on an older processor which does not support this (older than Sandy Bridge for AVX for example).

Comment: @cdarke, I have checked the installations and done the installation again. I don't think so there is any installation error.What i might think is that, running from terminal might be causing an erroras it does not support GUI. Can you tell how to support GUI.
There is something which code is not able to process.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like dlib can't create image window in your case. Possible reason of it - incorrect dlib installation. As Dlib's documentation describes (readme.txt), you should install it by running setup.py:

```
COMPILING DLIB Python API
   Before you can run the Python example programs you must compile dlib. Type:
       python setup.py install
   or type
       python setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS
   if you have a CPU that supports AVX instructions, since this makes some
   things run faster.
```

Also you will need libx11-dev installed (sudo apt-get install libx11-dev) before running setup.py

Check installation script messages to see any possible errors, and if you see them - update your question to describe situation

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this and it was because the python module was being compiled with SSE4 instructions but my CPU only supports SSE2. Open tools/python/CMakeLists.txt and edit the line

```
set(USE_SSE4_INSTRUCTIONS ON CACHE BOOL "Use SSE4 instructions")
```

In my case I changed it to

```
set(USE_SSE2_INSTRUCTIONS ON CACHE BOOL "Use SSE2 instructions")
```